# How to remove Grub Rescue?

Tags: windows-7, windows, ssd, grub, bootloader

**Okay, before you flag this as duplicate, let me explain my exact situation.**

I had Win 7 installed on HDD1. I then installed Ubuntu on HDD2 as dual boat using unetbootin. Then, I installed a fresh copy of Win 8 on HDD1, after formatting. Later I decided I no longer want linux, since I didn't use it much. So I just formatted the partition using disk manager from Win 8.

Everything was fine, I could boot into windows 8 just fine from win 8 bootloader.

Two days ago I got an SSD. So I cloned HDD1 (Win 8) over to the SSD. I rebooted the PC and tried to boot from the SSD with the other HDD's uplugged. This sent me immediately into GRUB RESCUE. Okay...

Plugged back in other two drives, selected HDD1 to boot from, Win 8 loaded. Decided to install win 7 onto SSD as fresh copy (using an ISO that I ran from the drive). Reboot, boot from SSD... still GRUB... weird.

Reboot, boot from HDD1, Win 7 is an option here. It loads up fine. Reboot, go into Windows Recovery, `bootrec /fixmbr`. Still GRUB from SSD.

Reboot into recovery, `bootsect /nt60 C:` ... Still GRUB. Tried with D:, E: and F: as well.

I can't seem to load up windows without selecting HDD1 as the boot drive. Every time it tried to load from only the SSD it sends me into GRUB.

How can I fix my bootloader and completely remove GRUB from my system?

I don't have a windows install DVD, just the ISO. I don't have any blank DVD's to burn it and the only thing I have that resembles a flash drive is my Galaxy S 4. I can get into windows recovery command prompt and run commands there. I can also get into Win 7 if I boot from HDD1.

HDD0 is a 1TB media/data storage drive.

HDD0 is C: 
HDD1 is D: 
HDD2 is E: 
SSD   is F:

Comment: Have you run `bootrec /fixmbr` on the SSD? That is where GRUB is, it won't work is you run `bootrec` from your C: drive.